# Are they similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Do $\begin{bmatrix}
0&i&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix} $ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\-i&0&0\\0&1&0
\end{bmatrix} $  are similar.Is this True/false

Clearly both are nilpotent and one is conjucate transpose of other but how to know if they are similar.i'm stuck. Please help me

Comment: Why negative vote

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It is more likely that you'll receive an answer if you showed us that you've made an effort

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to start

Comment: Oh don't mind the downvoters, they have a habit of downvoting posts that doesn't show efforts (and without explaining why)

Comment: I've made up for it by upvoting. Just make sure you show that you've tried next time

Comment: Sure............

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: both matrices have the same characteristic polynomial $p(x)=x^3$, and for both that is also the minimal polynomial. What can you conclude about their Jordan canonical forms?

Comment: I dont know jordan form any other way?

Comment: Well, that's one of the reasons why people on this forum ask to show what you tried-because that way it will also be clear how much do you know about the problem. I'll try to think of another solution.

Comment: Btw what is answer true or false.... Next time if i ask i will add details as much as i xan

Comment: They are similar. Matrices of order at most $3\times 3$ (not true for higher dimension matrices) are similar if and only if their characteristic and minimal polynomials are the same. I never thought about proving this lemma without Jordan form though.